# Проблема с XPath в XSLT

Tags: xml, xpath, xslt

XML файл по своей сути состоит из двух частей:

1. <posts> - внутри содержатся посты
2. <users> - внутри содержится информация о пользователях

Пример xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="blog.xsl"?>

<blog xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.w3.org blog.xsd">

  <posts>

    <post>
      <topic>Human Resource Machine</topic>
      <keyword>C#</keyword>
      <keyword>Game</keyword>
      <keyword>HRM</keyword>
      <date>2020-12-03</date>
      <message>Пишу тут клон игры Human Resource Machine для лабы по шарпу)))</message>
      <file src="images/hrm.gif" name="hrm"/>
      <comment user="1">
        <date>2020-12-03</date>
        <message>А на чем пишешь-то?</message>
        <comment user="0">
          <date>2020-12-03</date>
          <message>На винформах)))</message>
          <comment user="1">
            <date>2020-12-03</date>
            <message>Ты псих...</message>
            <comment user="0">
              <date>2020-12-03</date>
              <message>Я знаю...</message>
            </comment>
          </comment>
        </comment>
      </comment>
    </post>

  </posts>

  <users>

    <user id="0" admin="true">
      <name>A.L.E.X.</name>
      <phone>+380990315102</phone>
      <mail>akrutko472@gmail.com</mail>
    </user>

    <user id="1" admin="false">
      <name>XXX</name>
      <phone>+88005553535</phone>
      <mail>xxx@gmail.com</mail>
    </user>

  </users>

</blog>
```

Более подробно через xsd:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
elementFormDefault="qualified">

  <xs:simpleType name="nameType">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
      <xs:minLength value="1"></xs:minLength>
      <xs:maxLength value="25"></xs:maxLength>
    </xs:restriction>
  </xs:simpleType>

  <xs:simpleType name = "phoneType">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
      <xs:pattern value="^\+? ?\d([ -]?\d){9,14}$"/>
    </xs:restriction>
  </xs:simpleType>

  <xs:simpleType name = "mailType">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
      <xs:pattern value="^\w[\.\w]*@[\w]+\.[A-Za-z]+$"/>
    </xs:restriction>
  </xs:simpleType>

  <xs:simpleType name="messageType">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
      <xs:maxLength value="1000"></xs:maxLength>
    </xs:restriction>
  </xs:simpleType>

  <xs:complexType name="fileType">
    <xs:attribute name="src" type="xs:anyURI" use="required"/>
    <xs:attribute name="name" type="nameType" use="optional" />
  </xs:complexType>

  <xs:complexType name="postType">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="topic" type="nameType"></xs:element>
      <xs:element name="keyword" type="nameType" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"></xs:element>
      <xs:element name="date" type="xs:date"></xs:element>
      <xs:element name="message" type="messageType"></xs:element>
      <xs:element name="file" type="fileType" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="10"></xs:element>
      <xs:element name="comment" type="commentType" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"></xs:element>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>

  <xs:complexType name="commentType">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="date" type="xs:date"></xs:element>
      <xs:element name="message" type="messageType"></xs:element>
      <xs:element name="file" type="fileType" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="3"></xs:element>
      <xs:element name="comment" type="commentType" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"></xs:element>
    </xs:sequence>
    <xs:attribute name="user" type="xs:nonNegativeInteger" use="required"/>
  </xs:complexType>

  <xs:complexType name="userType">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="name" type="nameType"/>
      <xs:element name="phone" type="phoneType"/>
      <xs:element name="mail" type="mailType"/>
    </xs:sequence>
    <xs:attribute name="id" type="xs:nonNegativeInteger" use="required"/>
    <xs:attribute name="admin" type="xs:boolean" default="false"/>
  </xs:complexType>

  <xs:complexType name="postsType">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name = "post" type="postType" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"></xs:element>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>

  <xs:complexType name ="usersType">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name = "user" type="userType" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"></xs:element>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>

  <xs:complexType name="blogType">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="posts" type="postsType"></xs:element>
      <xs:element name="users" type="usersType"></xs:element>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>

  <xs:element name ="blog" type="blogType"></xs:element>

</xs:schema>
```

В XSLT я хочу неподсредственно зарендерить внутри комментариев ник пользователя. И в этом моменте наступают трудности (эта строчка вызывается в области видимости конкретного <comment>):

```
<xsl:value-of select="/blog/users/user[@id = '{@user}']/name"/>
```

По-идее все правильно, но в итоге ничего не происходит. При этом работают частные случаи, например:

```
<xsl:value-of select="/blog/users/user[@id = '1']/name"/>
```

Также я зарендерил что-то на уровне:

```
<p class="/blog/users/user[@id = '{@user}']/name"/>
```

И в отрендеренной странице класс <p> в действительности будет правильным, тоесть сам XPath написан корректно, но почему-то XSLT не хочет обрабатывать путь правильно внутри <xsl:value-of>. Единственное предположение, что для этого существует другая xsl - инструкция, о существовании которой я даже не предпологаю. Также возможно, что для этого нужно использовать переменные, многое пробовал - в итоге ничего не вышло. Или сущность проблемы заключается в другом?

Максимально урезанный xsl:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
                xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

  <!--Рекурсивно вызываемый шаблон комментария-->
  <xsl:template name="comment">
    
    <div class="comment">
      
      <p class="author">
        <xsl:value-of select="/blog/users/user[@id = '1']/name"/> <!--Конкретный пользователь - работает-->
        <p class="/blog/users/user[@id = '{@user}']/name"/> <!--XPath как класс <p> - значение корректно-->
        <xsl:value-of select="/blog/users/user[@id = '{@user}']/name"/> <!--Уже не работает...-->
      </p>
      
      <p><xsl:value-of select="message"/></p>
      <div class="info"><xsl:value-of select="date"/></div>

      <xsl:if test="comment">
        <hr/>
        <details>
          <summary>Ответы</summary>
          <xsl:for-each select="comment">
            <xsl:call-template name="comment"/>
          </xsl:for-each>
        </details>
      </xsl:if>
      
    </div>
  
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="/">

  <html>

    <head>
        <meta charset = "UTF-8"/>
        <title>Блог</title>
        <link rel = "stylesheet" href = "styles/main.css"/>
        <script src="scripts/main.js" defer="true"></script>
    </head>

    <body>

      <xsl:for-each select="blog/posts/post">

        <div class="post">

          <div class="topic"><xsl:value-of select="topic"/></div>

          <div class = "keywords">
            <xsl:for-each select="keyword">
              <span><xsl:value-of select="."/></span>
            </xsl:for-each>
          </div>
          
          <p><xsl:value-of select="message"/></p>
          <div class="info"><xsl:value-of select="date"/></div>

          <xsl:if test="comment">
            <hr/>
            <details>
              <summary>Комментарии</summary>
              <xsl:for-each select="comment">
                <xsl:call-template name="comment"/>
              </xsl:for-each>
            </details>
          </xsl:if>
        
        </div>

      </xsl:for-each>

    </body>

  </html>
  
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Ожидаемый результат:

[image: Отображение поста на странице]

Это задание лабораторной работы, которая не предусматривает серверную часть, и поэтому xslt-процессор как таковой не используется. Иными словами, встроенный в браузер xslt-процессор.

Comment: Было бы здорово, если бы вы могли предоставить минимально воспроизводимый пример:
(1) Начальный XML.
(2) Ваша логика и XSLT, который пытался ее реализовать.
(3) Желаемый результат.
(4) XSLT-процессор и его версия.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Единственное предположение, что для этого существует другая xsl -
> инструкция, о существовании которой я даже не предпологаю.

Это правильное предположение. Просто был нужен параметр. Это предпочтительный способ по сравнению с простой переменной.

Пожалуйста, посмотрите ниже как это сделать.

**XSLT**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output indent="yes" method="html"/>

    <xsl:template name="comment">
        <xsl:param name="user"/>
        <div class="comment">

            <p class="author">
                <xsl:value-of select="/blog/users/user[@id = $user]/name"/>
            </p>

            <p>
                <xsl:value-of select="message"/>
            </p>
            <div class="info">
                <xsl:value-of select="date"/>
            </div>

            <xsl:if test="comment">
                <hr/>
                <details>
                    <summary>Ответы</summary>
                    <xsl:for-each select="comment">
                        <xsl:call-template name="comment">
                            <xsl:with-param name="user" select="@user"/>
                        </xsl:call-template>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </details>
            </xsl:if>
        </div>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="/blog">
        <html>
            <head>
                <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
                <title>Блог</title>
                <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/main.css"/>
                <script src="scripts/main.js" defer="true"></script>
            </head>
            <body>
                <xsl:for-each select="posts/post">
                    <div class="post">

                        <div class="topic">
                            <xsl:value-of select="topic"/>
                        </div>

                        <div class="keywords">
                            <xsl:for-each select="keyword">
                                <span>
                                    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                                </span>
                            </xsl:for-each>
                        </div>

                        <p>
                            <xsl:value-of select="message"/>
                        </p>
                        <div class="info">
                            <xsl:value-of select="date"/>
                        </div>

                        <xsl:if test="comment">
                            <hr/>
                            <details>
                                <summary>Комментарии</summary>
                                <xsl:for-each select="comment">
                                    <xsl:call-template name="comment">
                                        <xsl:with-param name="user" select="@user"/>
                                    </xsl:call-template>
                                </xsl:for-each>
                            </details>
                        </xsl:if>
                    </div>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 1):

Оказывается все намного банальней и проще:

```
<xsl:variable name="id" select="@user"/>
<xsl:value-of select="/blog/users/user[@id = $id]/name"/>
```

*Правильный ответ всегда оказывается самым скучным...*